# how to slide down the action bar in android to display something like coversation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

i want to display the conversation between me and admin when i dragged the action bar. since i was new to android programming i dont know how to slide the action bar also. the following code is a decoy(dummy) code, coz its not letting me to post the question without sample code. please help me to drag or slide down the action bar to display conversation. thank you.

```
          import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
          import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.Menu;
          import android.view.MenuItem;
          import android.widget.Button;
          import android.view.View;

           public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
       bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

       }
         {

       }
       }


      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if  it      is         present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
      }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
      }
```